# Precision in summary output of lm R

Tags: r, precision, lm, summary, r-exams

I am doing some exercises using package r-exams, in which I print a summary from an `lm` object and ask students things like, “which is the estimated value of the intercept”. The idea is that the student copies the values of the summary output and use that value as the correct answer. The issue here is that I use the values from `coef()` function as the correct answers, but this is not a good idea since the precision of these values are quite different from the precision of the values shown in the `summary` output. Here is an example:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
## DATA GENERATION
xbreaks<-c(runif(1,4,4.8),runif(1,6,6.9),runif(1,7.8,8.5),runif(1,9,10))
ybreaks<-c(runif(1,500,1000),runif(1,1800,4000),runif(1,200,800))

b11<-(ybreaks[2]-ybreaks[1])/(xbreaks[2]-xbreaks[1])
b10<-ybreaks[1]-b11*xbreaks[1]

b31<-(ybreaks[3]-ybreaks[2])/(xbreaks[4]-xbreaks[3])
b30<-ybreaks[2]-b31*xbreaks[3]
points_df<-data.frame(x=xbreaks,y=ybreaks[c(1,2,2,3)])

n<-rpois(3,120)

x1<-runif(n[1],xbreaks[1],xbreaks[2])
x2<-runif(n[2],xbreaks[2],xbreaks[3])
x3<-runif(n[3],xbreaks[3],xbreaks[4])

y<-c(b10+b11*x1+rnorm(n[1],0,200),
     ybreaks[2]+rnorm(n[2],0,200),
     b30+b31*x3+rnorm(n[3],0,200))

z0_aw<-data.frame(ph=c(x1,x2,x3),UFC=y,case=factor(c(rep(1,n[1]),rep(2,n[2]),rep(3,n[3]))))
mean_x<-z0_aw$ph%>% mean %>% round(2)
caserng<-sample(1:4,1)
modrng<-sample(1:2,1)
if(caserng!=4){
  z0_aw<-z0_aw[z0_aw$case == caserng,]
}

if(modrng==1){
  m0<-lm(UFC~ph,data=z0_aw)
}else{
  cl <- call("lm", formula = UFC ~ I(ph - mean_x), data = as.name("z0_aw"))
  cl$formula[[3]][[2]][[3]] <- mean_x
  m0<-eval(cl)
}

summary(m0)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = UFC ~ I(ph - 7.2), data = z0_aw)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -555.53 -121.98    5.46  115.38  457.08 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  2726.86      57.33   47.57   <2e-16 ***
#> I(ph - 7.2)  -840.05      31.46  -26.70   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 182.7 on 116 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8601, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8589 
#> F-statistic: 713.1 on 1 and 116 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

coef(m0)
#> (Intercept) I(ph - 7.2) 
#>   2726.8605   -840.0515
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Suppose that `extol: 0.0001` in r-exams is set, and the student is asked to give the estimated value of the intercept. The student will get a wrong answer since he will answer `2726.86` but the correct answer from `coef` is `2726.8605` .

As can be seen, output of `summary` uses 2 decimals, whereas `coef()` values has quite more precision. I want to know how many decimals is summary using in order to apply the same format to values produced by `coef()`. This will ensure that the answer provided by the student is the same as the `summary` output.

I just want to do this:

`answers<-coef(m0) %>% format(digits=dsum) %>% as.numeric()`

where `dsum` is the number of digits used also by the summary output.

Note: retain a precision of 4 decimals is needed since I also ask students about the `R-squared` value provided in the same `summary` output, so it is not a good idea to set  `extol: 0.01` for example. Also the problems are generated at random and the magnitude of the estimated coefficients changes, as I have noted that this is directly related to the precision used in `summary` output.

Comment: `print(summary(m0), digits=6)` shows `2726.8605` in the `Estimate` column. It defaults go `getOption("digits")-3` (from `?summary.lm`), so you can get the same effect with `options(digits=9); summary(m0);`.

Comment: for this case if I do `max(3, getOption("digits") – 3)` I get 4, but clearly output is using 2 digits in estimate column. If I do `print(summary(m0), digits=6)` then estimate column now gets 4 digits but `R-squared` gets now 6 digits. I really don't understand how this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is being applied rather universally. I believe that it is not intended to be a perfect report format, more-so a quick summarization of the model to see where to go next. This is often used as *the* reporting format, which is generally okay, but I believe everybody has their own preferences on various aspects (decimals, stars, etc), and adding `print` arguments to customize digits on every single component of the summary seems perhaps over-optionizing.

Comment: Long-story-short, I sympathize with your academic issue here, but I think the question to the students needs to be clear to say something like *"precision must be to 0.0001, you may need `coef` to get the requested precision"*. Or you should consider accepting `2726.86` as an acceptable answer.

Comment: I recall having similar issues in understanding "required precision" on assignments to my students (when I taught). For some, the concepts of *precision* and *significant digits* were unclear and needed reinforcement; once that was done, *then* it was necessary to provide guidance on ancillary methods to get to the required precision of an object in R.

Comment: is there a way to see how is the code of  `print(summary(m0), digits=6)` working? I mean, I can see the code of the function `summary.lm` easily, but how to do this for the printing method for `summary.lm` ?

Comment: `stats:::print.summary.lm`. It is not exported, it is available through normal S3 method-dispatch, so you have to use triple colons to find the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some useful information for such questions in R/exams:**

- The `extol` can also be a vector so that you can set different tolerances for coefficients and R-squared etc.
- When asking about the R-squared, though, I typically ask for it "in percent". Then the same tolerance may be suitable as for the coefficients.
- I would recommend to control the size of the coefficients suitably so that `digits` and `extol` can be set accordingly.
- Personally, I typically store the `exsolution` at a higher precision than I request from the students. For example, `exsolution` could be `12.345678` while I only set `extol` to `0.01`. This makes sure that when the correct answer is rounded to two decimal places it is inside the correct interval determined by `exsolution` and `extol`.

**Details on formatting of the coefficients in the summary:**

- It is not obvious where exactly the formatting happens: The `summary()` method for `lm` objects returns an object of class `summary.lm` which has its own `print()` method which in turn calls `printCoefmat()`. The latter is the function that does the actual formatting.
- When setting the `digits` in these functions, this controls the number of *significant digits* and not the number of *decimal places*. This is particularly important when the coefficients become relatively large (say, in the thousands or more).
- The coefficients are not formatted individually but jointly with the corresponding standard errors. The details depend on the `digits`, the size of both coefficients and standard errors, and whether any coefficients are aliased or exactly zero etc.
- Without aliased/zero coefficients the formatting from `summary(m0)` can be replicated using `format_coef(m0)` as defined below. That's essentially the boiled-down code from `printCoefmat()`.

  ```
  format_coef <- function(object, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 2L)) {
    coef_se <- summary(object)$coefficients[, 1L:2L]
    digmin <- 1L + floor(log10(range(abs(coef_se))))
    format(round(coef_se, max(1L, digits - digmin)), digits = digits)[, 1L]
  }
  ```

Comment: can `extol` be also a vector in a `extype: cloze` question? how should I define that vector? something like`extol: c(.01,.01,.0001)` gives some warnings. I have like 8 question, which only 3 of them are numeric.

Comment: Like the other fields as well: `exsolution: 1.23|4.56` and `extol: 0.01|0.0001`. It should be possible to have the same length for `extol` as for `exsolution` and only fill in the elements you need.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issues? If so it would be great to either accept my answer or to post a more complete answer yourself. Then the question would appear as resolved here on StackOverflow. If you couldn't resolve the issue, yet, please refine the question so that we can find an answer.

Comment: `exsolution` as vector did improve the situation, but there are some cases in which summary output differs from that obtained from `coef` even using `format(coef(m0),digits=xxx)`. Those cases are related when `coef` are in thousands orders of magnitude. For me it is still an open problem to achieve the exact same numbers printed by summary and to store that in an R object, in a consistent way.

Comment: OK, I have extended my answer and divided it into R/exams-specific and summary.lm-specific aspects. Also, I have tracked down how exactly the coefficients in the summary are formatted. I hope the answer covers all aspects that are relevant to you now.